# Ajax, Html: can't generate the content of SELECT tag

Tags: html, ajax

i have the following html code

```
<select id="c0"  name="countries" onchange="show_other()">
  <option value="1">something</option>
  <div id="c1">

  </div>
</select>
```

i have the option "something", and i want to generate other options via Ajax.
but if i try to this

```
  document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```

it doesn't work, but

```
 document.getElementById('c0').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```

works fine, but i need to keep the first option.
could you explain what is the problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allowed to place `<div>` elements within a `<select>` tag. Only `<option>` elements are allowed within `<select>`s.

To achieve what you're looking to do, try something like this:

```
document.getElementById('c0').innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

If your goal is to have one static element in there and just replace the elements that would otherwise go in the `<div>`, what you're going to want to do is code the default options into your JS:

```
document.getElementById('c0').innerHTML = '<option value="1">something</option>' + xmlhttp.responseText;
```

You can also have a dummy select that you pull that value from:

```
document.getElementById('c0').innerHTML = document.getElementById('dummyselect').innerHTML + xmlhttp.responseText;
```

in conjunction with

```
<select id="dummyselect" style="display:none;">
    <option value="1">something</option>
</select>
<select id="c0"></select>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The C1 div is invalidly nested in the select element, at least according to your example.

Comment: @BradBrening why invalidly? <select id="c0"  name="countries" onchange="show_other()">
  <div id="c1">
      <option value="1">something</option>
  </div>
</select>
works fine